# Unwanted line height increase with chemformula

Tags: vertical-alignment, chemformula

I'm getting an unwanted line skip between tabular lines when one of the the lines contains a bond in a `\ch` formula, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\lineskiplimit=-1em

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{r}
\hline
\ch{H2O} \\
\ch{CH3OCH3} \\
\ch{H3PO4} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
\ch{H2O} \\
\ch{CH3-O-CH3} \\
\ch{H3PO4} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The left table has a larger separation between the 1st and 2nd lines, and it's not affected by `\lineskiplimit`. The relevant difference is `\ch{CH3-O-CH3}` vs. `\ch{CH3OCH3}`.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Could you please open a feature request/bug report on https://github.com/cgnieder/chemformula/issues ?

Comment: The code for the bond inserts a 10pt high box, which is definitely too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed in `chemformula` version 4.15i:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}[2020/02/01]% v4.15i or newer

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{r}
    \hline
     \ch{H2O} \\
     \ch{CH3OCH3} \\
     \ch{H3PO4} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \hline
     \ch{H2O} \\
     \ch{CH3-O-CH3} \\
     \ch{H3PO4} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In older versions the following code in the preamble should do:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \chemformula_bond:n #1
  {
    \chemformula_skip_nobreak:N \l__chemformula_bond_space_dim
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__chemformula_tmpa_box {K}
    \dim_set:Nn \l__chemformula_tmpa_dim { \box_ht:N \l__chemformula_tmpa_box }
    \chemformula_tikz:nn
      {
        inner~sep   = 0pt ,
        outer~sep   = 0pt ,
        text~height = \l__chemformula_tmpa_dim ,
        baseline    = (chemformula-bond-ground.base)
      }
      {
        \coordinate (chemformula-bond-ground) at (0pt,0pt) ;
        \draw (chemformula-bond-ground) ++ (0pt,.5\l__chemformula_tmpa_dim)
          coordinate (chemformula-bond-start) ;
        \draw (chemformula-bond-start) ++(\l__chemformula_bond_dim ,0pt)
          coordinate (chemformula-bond-end) ;
        \tl_if_blank:nTF {#1}
          { \__chemformula_bond_draw:n {single} }
          { \__chemformula_bond_draw:n {#1} }
      }
    \chemformula_skip_nobreak_penalty:NV
      \l__chemformula_bond_space_dim
      \l__chemformula_bond_penalty_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Remark: In the line `\hbox_set:Nn \l__chemformula_tmpa_box {K}` `K` doesn't need to be `K`. Any capital letter without descender should so with minimal differences on the position of the bond.

(Note to self: should probably place the bonds on the math axis…)

Comment: Is there no way to "backport" the fix to older versions?

Comment: @Jellby please see the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Manual fix: you can pretend that `\ch{CH3-O-CH3` has zero height using `\raisebox{0pt}[0pt]{\ch{CH3-O-CH3}}`, or pretend that it has the same height as `\ch{CH3OCH3}` (here: using `\heightof` from the `calc` package):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r}
\hline
\ch{H2O} \\
\ch{CH3OCH3} \\
\ch{H3PO4} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
%
\qquad
%
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
\ch{H2O} \\
\raisebox{0pt}[\heightof{\ch{CH3OCH3}}]{\ch{CH3-O-CH3}} \\
\ch{H3PO4} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Of course, you can obtain nicer rules using the `booktabs` package, but that is orthogonal to the question:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r}
\toprule
\ch{H2O} \\
\ch{CH3OCH3} \\
\ch{H3PO4} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
%
\qquad
%
\begin{tabular}{l}
\toprule
\ch{H2O} \\
\raisebox{0pt}[\heightof{\ch{CH3OCH3}}]{\ch{CH3-O-CH3}} \\
\ch{H3PO4} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I know about booktabs, but it's not a MWE with it ;) The lines are actually not relevant either, they were just to make the height difference more clearly.

Comment: Sure, that's why I mentioned it last and said it is orthogonal to the question.